# Go `defer` does not behave as expected when Unmount

Tags: go

Here is my main.go, and I use `go run main.go run sh` to create a process which runs shell in it.

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "path/filepath"
    "strconv"
    "syscall"

    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        logrus.Errorf("missing commands")
        return
    }
    switch os.Args[1] {
    case "run":
        run()
    case "child":
        child()
    default:
        logrus.Errorf("wrong command")
        return
    }
}

func run() {
    logrus.Info("Setting up...")
    cmd := exec.Command("/proc/self/exe", append([]string{"child"}, os.Args[2:]...)...)
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
        Cloneflags: syscall.CLONE_NEWUTS | syscall.CLONE_NEWPID | syscall.CLONE_NEWNS,
    }
    check(cmd.Run())
}

func child() {
    logrus.Infof("Running %v", os.Args[2:])
    cmd := exec.Command(os.Args[2], os.Args[3:]...)
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    check(syscall.Sethostname([]byte("newhost")))
    check(syscall.Chroot("/root/busybox"))
    check(os.Chdir("/"))
    check(syscall.Mount("proc", "proc", "proc", 0, ""))
    check(syscall.Mount("tempdir", "temp", "tmpfs", 0, ""))
    check(cmd.Run())
    check(syscall.Unmount("proc", 0))
    check(syscall.Unmount("temp", 0))
}

func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Errorln(err)
    }
}
```

When I run `mount` in the new shell, it returns

```
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
tempdir on /temp type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
```

that just works fine.

But when I change the child function into

```
func child() {
    ...
    check(os.Chdir("/"))
    check(syscall.Mount("proc", "proc", "proc", 0, ""))
    check(syscall.Mount("tempdir", "temp", "tmpfs", 0, ""))
    defer check(syscall.Unmount("proc", 0))
    defer check(syscall.Unmount("temp", 0))
    check(cmd.Run())
}
```

and run `mount` again, it returns `mount: no /proc/mounts`.

`defer` is illustrated to defer the function after it to the end of the outer function. But it seems that `syscall.Umount()` is invoked before `cmd.Run()`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know if it's the problem or not, but the order of unmount is reversed in the deferred program.

Comment: but it seems that the file systems are unmounted before cmd.Run() is invoked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
defer check(syscall.Unmount("proc", 0))
defer check(syscall.Unmount("temp", 0))
```

You are defering the `check`-call, but it's arguments are evaluated immediately, which means, `syscall.Unmount` is not defered. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements

> Each time a "defer" statement executes, **the function value and
>   parameters to the call are evaluated as usual and saved anew** but the
>   actual function is not invoked. Instead, deferred functions are
>   invoked immediately before the surrounding function returns, in the
>   reverse order they were deferred. If a deferred function value
>   evaluates to nil, execution panics when the function is invoked, not
>   when the "defer" statement is executed.

Use a anonymous function if you can't get rid of the check-call:

```
defer func() { check(syscall.Unmount("proc", 0)) }()
defer func() { check(syscall.Unmount("temp", 0)) }()
```

Answer (score 1):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Defer statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements)
>
> Each time a "defer" statement executes, the function value and
>   parameters to the call are evaluated as usual and saved anew but the
>   actual function is not invoked. Instead,
>   deferred functions are invoked immediately before the surrounding
>   function returns, in the **reverse order** they were deferred.

For

```
check(cmd.Run())
check(syscall.Unmount("proc", 0))
check(syscall.Unmount("temp", 0))
```

defer in reverse order

```
defer check(syscall.Unmount("temp", 0))
defer check(syscall.Unmount("proc", 0))
check(cmd.Run())
```

---

For your second problem, "the file systems are unmounted before `cmd.Run()` is invoked ", "Each time a "defer" statement executes, the function value and parameters to the call are evaluated as usual and saved anew but the actual function is not invoked."

Comment: but it seems that the file systems are unmounted before cmd.Run() is invoked

Comment: @KasheemLew: See my revised answer for this problem.